# How to just run type check on vue files without runnning webpack build?

Tags: typescript, vue-cli-3

I would like to just type check vue files without building the whole application. Any way to do this?

I know `vue-cli-service serve` and `vue-cli-service build` will do typecheck by `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`, but it build the whole application and it's slow.

Comment: You can try the [`@vuedx/typecheck`](https://github.com/znck/vue-developer-experience/tree/main/packages/typecheck) package, as they said

> A command line tool to check types, functionally equivalent to `tsc --noEmit` but supports Vue.

Comment: thanks for the information

Comment: There's also https://github.com/policyfly/vue-script-tsc which is a lightweight version which I've just released

Answer (score 2):

For Vue 3 you can use [vue-tsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tsc), to do this

```sh
vue-tsc --noEmit
```

Comment: Does this work with webpack?

Comment: I don't see a reason to not work with webpack if you are using vue 3, so probably yes

Comment: for me it was necessary to delete the created file `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` before every run. Otherwise the type check did not work